# What to do if paint peeling on bathroom walls?

Tags: painting, paint

Paint has peeled from the walls (not ceiling) of my bathroom.

Any chance I will know what is causing it? (This has happened after  at least 5 years of use, we are not the original owner/painter). What should I look for to find the cause?

Do I need to apply any anti-bacterial compound before painting again (it has been like that for 5 months)?

Do I need to apply any special primer?

What type of paint should I use?

Comment: All of what was said below, but... do you have an exhaust fan? And do you use it? If you don't have one, moisture builds up in bathrooms and eventually ruins the paint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...what is causing it?

There is a very high probability that the person who applied it did not sand the gloss off of the existing paint prior to applying the new paint (bathroom paint, typically, has a gloss to it).

> Do I need to apply any anti-bacterial compound before painting again... ?

No

> Do I need to apply any special primer?

Not if you prepare it properly, meaning sand off all unsound paint that is peeling or seems like it might peel, and ensuring all surfaces below the peeled-off paint are also de-glossed. Make sure the wall is smooth, dull, and clean and you can repaint.

Notes-

- if you paint over existing unsound paint, it will all peel again eventually
- if you patch (or sand through to bare plaster) you will need to prime
- if you choose to use a high quality bonding primer (after proper surface preparation) it will do nothing but help.